# Where does Linux Mint keep the files for default desktop wallpapers?

Tags: linux, linux-mint, desktop-customization

Under Cinnamon Settings > Backgrounds, there are a lot of images I would like to move to my windows partition to use as wallpapers. Where exactly are these files located?

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I suppose your Linux Mint comes with [GNOME](http://www.gnome.org/) and normally, it should be under `/usr/share/backgrounds` .

Comment: Found it in /usr/share/backgrounds/linuxmint-nadia-extra. Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

`Mint` change background in each release, could get background of previous release.

**Command - install background**:

- `sudo apt-get install mint-backgrounds-<release_name>`, install a specific release,
- `sudo apt-get install mint-backgrounds-*`, all release,

Answer (score 0):

Linux Mint and Ubuntu derivatives will have their backgrounds in `/usr/share/backgrounds/`
The ones your looking for should be in their or a sub folder.